# Relationship not being created, match by Id not returning results

Tags: neo4j

I'm just getting started with Neo4j.

I'm trying to do a complex LOAD FROM CSV but I don't seem to be getting the relations part right.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:/Users/brestrepo/Krossover/neo4j/access_control_games.csv" AS csvLine
MERGE (game:Game
    {
        id: toInt(csvLine.id),
        datePlayed: csvLine.date_played,
        type: csvLine.type,
        createdAt: csvLine.created_at,
        updatedAt: csvLine.updated_at
    }
)
FOREACH(ignoreMe IN CASE WHEN trim(csvLine.deleted_at) <> "" THEN [1] ELSE [] END | SET game.deletedAt = csvLine.deleted_at)
WITH csvLine, game
MATCH (team:TEAM { id: toInt(csvLine.created_by_team_id)}),(game:Game { id: toInt(csvLine.id)})
CREATE (team)-[:OWNER_TEAM { }]->(game)
WITH csvLine, game
MATCH (user:User { id: toInt(csvLine.created_by_user_id)}),(game:Game { id: toInt(csvLine.id)})
CREATE (user)-[:OWNER_USER { }]->(game)
WITH csvLine, game
MATCH (team_away:TEAM { id: toInt(csvLine.team_away_id)}),(game:Game { id: toInt(csvLine.id)})
CREATE (team_away)-[:AWAY_TEAM { }]->(game)
WITH csvLine, game
MATCH (team_home:TEAM { id: toInt(csvLine.team_home_id)}),(game:Game { id: toInt(csvLine.id)})
CREATE (team_home)-[:HOME_TEAM { }]->(game)
RETURN game
```

I think that the MATCH is that's causing this problem. The Match is unable to find a game.

I do get games when I do:
**MATCH (game:Game) return game LIMIT 1**

```
{
  "records": [
    {
      "keys": [
        "game"
      ],
      "length": 1,
      "_fields": [
        {
          "identity": {
            "low": 31891,
            "high": 0
          },
          "labels": [
            "Game"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "createdAt": "2014-07-18 19:38:32",
            "deletedAt": "NULL",
            "id": {
              "low": 285,
              "high": 0
            },
            "type": "2",
            "datePlayed": "2013-10-12 04:00:00",
            "updatedAt": "2016-03-25 15:28:41"
          },
          "id": "31891"
        }
      ],
      "_fieldLookup": {
        "game": 0
      }
    }
  ],
}
```

But then, when I do
**MATCH (game:Game {id: 31891}) return game;**

> (no changes, no records)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Try `MATCH (game:Game) ID(game)=31891 return game;`.

Comment: (1) Since your `WITH` clauses are always passing `game` forward, there is no reason for you to ever `MATCH` on `game`. (2) Are you sure the `TEAM` and `User` nodes that you are attempting to match all already exist?

Comment: Note that there are two "id" fields in the record data. The one inside the "properties" map (285) is the one you set from the CSV value. The one outside the properties map that you tried for your lookup (31891) is the Neo4j internal id of the node (stdob-- mentioned how you'd look that up, if you needed to). For your sanity check, lookup the game with `{id: 285}`